# signal words for/of the present perfect

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is appropriate here or both are idiomatic? Do you see any difference for the mentioned context?

> Signal words **for** the present perfect are just, already ...
>
> Signal words **of** the present perfect are just, already ...

Comment: "Signal" can be used with "of"; [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/signal) gives "The loss is a clear signal of his deteriorating confidence." But not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which preposition is appropriate here or both are idiomatic?

It should be "for". As a confirmation, searching the internet for the text "Signal words of the present perfect are just, already" finds this search result at the top:

"The typical signal words for the present perfect simple are" (english.lingolia.com)

While the word "of" is bordering on plausible it doesn't sound quite right.

"of" expresses origin, agency, composition, substance. "for" can mean appropriate, supporting, intended, for a purpose.

If you try to use "of" in this case, it seems to mean that the present perfect owns the signal words, which is not a typical abstraction, even if not far-fetched. "For" avoids the problem, and says "here is a tool for a purpose" which is a better relationship between the signal words and the grammatical tense.